# Bounties and deletion feature abuse

Tags: feature-request, bug, bounties, deleted-accounts, association-bonus

I have a potential exploit for the association bonus awarded and the bounty system. Primarily, it deals with reputation-inflation.

Initiation and motivation:

Most of us at least have 200 reputation on multiple sites. Assume a person with intentions to raise a child account and make it a *spoilt* child or freely promote their content on Stack Exchange.

Steps:

1. Have at least 200 reputation to get the association bonus.
2. Create an account **A_1** on any X.stackexchange.com (X of choice).
3. Receive an association bonus on joining. Ask a mediocre-good question (to avoid closure/duplicates), wait two days and put out a 100 reputation bounty.
4. Create a puppet/child account **C_1**. Answer that question with the child account. Award yourself (child) the bounty (and of course upvote and mark as correct)
5. (Fun part) Delete **A_1** :)
6. Re-create **A_1**, while True: repeat step **3 to 6**

Apart from the **spoilt-child** exploit, one might also use it for *free* promotion of their questions and may not create a child.

Also related [except for the exploit part](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270400/) and [a bit modified and large scale version](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-similar-new-users) (but this method is far more detectable unless multiple IP address bounce nodes are used).

Comment: Has this been tested? Deletion of questions with answers is restricted in some cases, but I'm not sure whether it would prevent this scenario.

Comment: @amon I recently deleted one of my accounts, the system preserved my upvoted question with upvoted answers, also probably you did a comprehensive mistake reading the steps, can I explain anyone?

Comment: +1. I've actually *seen* this being abused (minus the **C_1** / sockpuppetry part - just someone repeatedly using association bonuses to bounty the same post) on one site.

Comment: @Randal'Thor How about I delete this secret knowledge :P just kidding, but probably I should if this bug is squashed as rejected

Comment: As far as I remember, the sock puppet ring discussed at https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-similar-new-users used a similar scheme to gain reputation.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek As far as I read, it's about enormous number of accounts. Mine just takes 2 (to avoid detection, unless someone willingly uses TOR), also, the answer by Todd suggests that it is slightly different than what I have done. I have completely dissociated the post as user_abcdef

Comment: It takes *at least* 2. It doesn't stop working just because they happened to have many more accounts (which they abused in other ways). They may not have used exactly the same workflow, but the basic principle is similar (gain association bonus, dump it to another account using bounties).

Comment: You can abuse bounties in many creative ways. Us moderators won’t  hesitate to deal with abuses like these. You can’t block every possible abuse angle automatically but we *can* enforce common ground rules such as “don’t abuse the system”.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I highly doubt that you can stop or even deal with this abuse. I am on currently on TOR to verify if multiple bounces work. Consider an ID being operated with ghost location(which changes every time). And, what common ground rules are there....I propose that association bonus to be awarded just once (just like if an ID is suspended, the system remembers the suspension under the name user_abcdef), or maybe, exemption from bounty

Comment: @Cagliostro I’m not at liberty to reveal how much moderators can see in such cases but I’m not worried.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's not about worries, ofcourse it wont bring SE down, but the systematic abuse. I have seen some stray posts on m-SE where visibility of such things were revealed (although old). Think of those who are recently joining stack exchange/overflow and fall prey to such malpractices. Earning reputation on certain communities are very hard...giving reputation as bounty-even harder.